# How to handle PInteger in Delphi 5

Tags: pointers, delphi

I am recompiling a higher version of XE5 project to Delphi 5.

Please advise how to handle the following types in Delphi 5:

1. PInteger
2. PPAnsiChar
3. PPointerArray

I am getting an error when these datatypes are compiled.

The message:
"Undeclared identifier: 'PInteger'"

Comment: Look up the declaration of each type in the docwiki and you can answer your own question.

Comment: These are compiler errors, **not** exceptions. Exceptions occur at **runtime**.

Comment: Off topic: Be sure to keep the ANSI-Unicode difference in mind, especially when dealing with `PPAnsiChar` and the like.

Comment: @UliGerhardt: Exceptions (in the compiler) can also happen at compile time. I regularly get an AV error during compilation from the compiler... :-) - Nitpicking :-)

Answer (score 4):

In your XE5, locate the type you're getting an "undeclared identifier" on, then Ctrl-Click with the mouse on the identifier. It should then take you to the location of the type definition so that you can see how it is defined. You then need to add that type definition to your D5 project.

Take PInteger, for instance. If you ctrl-click on it in XE5 you should get to a line like this:

```
PInteger = System.PInteger;
```

this is just an alias for another type definition, so you need to repeat the ctrl-click on the System.PInteger part to find the underlying type definition:

```
PInteger      = ^Integer;
```

This is the line you need to include in your D5 project. Likewise you'll need these lines for the other types:

```
PPAnsiChar    = ^PAnsiChar;
PPointerArray = ^PointerArray;
```

and if PAnsiChar / PointerArray aren't defined in D5, add these lines (before the above two ones):

```
PointerArray = array [0..512*1024*1024 - 2] of Pointer;
PAnsiChar = ^CHAR;
```

I recommend that you take all these type definitions and place them in a single UNIT containing only these type definitions and call it something like "UNIT XE5" which you can then include in the other UNITs that need these types. That way, you ensure that the new types are identical and not multiple new definitions that may be incompatible in VAR parameters.

Comment: Technically, `PAnsiChar = ^CHAR;` should be `PAnsiChar = ^AnsiChar;` though `Char` is `AnsiChar` in D5, but I prefer to be more explicit. But `PAnsiChar` does exist in D5, so this is moot

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know, but was unsure if D5 had a definition of AnsiChar (I don't have such an old version installed). But if it already exists, then it's a moot point, as you say...